# Ruby Sinatra URL keeps appending

Tags: ruby

I have four buttons, and everytime I click the button it should send a post request (I'll show my code below).

This is my `books controller.rb`

```
post '/all?' do
    @books = # Books here
    haml :'books/index', locals: {books: @books}
  end

  post '/fantasy?' do
    @fantasy = # Fantasy books here
    haml :'books/index', locals: {fantasy: @fantasy}
  end
```

And this is my `index.haml` file:

```
%form{method: 'POST', action: "books/all"}
   %input.btn.btn-md{type: 'submit', value: 'All Books'}
%form{method: 'POST', action: "books/fantasy"}
   %input.btn.btn-md{type: 'submit', value: 'Fantasy'}
```

However, what happens is the following:
(1) URL: `localhost:8080/books`
(2) I click on the `all` button
(3) URL: `localhost:8080/books/all`
(4) I click on the `fantasy` button
(5) URL: `localhost:8080/books/books/fantasy`

This is the problem - how can I get it so on the second button click, it goes to `localhost:8080/books/fantasy` instead? I'm sure its a simple fix just not sure how. Thanks.

Comment: Do they have to be forms/buttons? Simple links should do just fine, I think.

Comment: It does have to be forms / buttons for design/UI purposes. My books controller is essentially just that and my index.haml is that as well.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using absolute URLs: `action: "/books/fantasy"`?

Comment: Ohh that was what I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the recommended way is to use absolute paths with the addition of the [`url`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra/Sinatra%2FHelpers:uri) helper. This should better future-proof your code in case it is mounted in a sub folder or behind a reverse proxy.

```
%form{method: 'POST', action: url("/books/fantasy")}
```